# Using Redis bitmap random numeric ID as offset

Tags: php, redis

I want to use a bitmap in Redis to store bits for analytics purposes. But with bitmaps, it is necessary to specify an `offset` position, with cli it looks like:

`> SETBIT mykey <offset> 1`

Usually, an offset would be an ID value from a database, so it's unique and sequential. But in my case I can't do that because the bits I want to save are not logged in users, but viewers on a web page, so they don't have an ID.

So it means I need to generate a random numeric value and use that as an offset. I'm going to be using PHP. So far I have tried this:

```php
$id = hexdec( substr( md5($uniqid()), 0, 10 ) );
```

That results in integers such as: `584657569161`. I don't want to use such a big integer as an offset if I don't need to. What is the most efficient way to generate a unique numeric value that will start with a small number, but then will increase based on the number of viewers already present?

Comment: You have to choose between random and range. If it is random, you must accept the entire range at all times. If it is incremental, you can start with a small range and increase. You *could* store the visitor addresses in a table with an autoincrmenting ID.

Comment: Starting with a small number is better, because for large integers, it may take a second or so to allocate it, according to Redis docs. I think I'll increment the counter for each new viewer, and use that counter integer as an offset, as suggested by Itamar Haber below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that may work for you:

1. Keep a counter in Redis, and `INCR` it for every new unique viewer ID
2. Map the result you got from the counter to the viewer ID with a Redis Hash - each field is an integer and the value is the viewer ID. Use this to resolve integer IDs into viewer IDs.
3. Repeat step 2 with a different Hash where the field is the viewer ID and the value is the integer, and use it to convert viewer to integer IDs.

Comment: Step 1 seems to be the most simple. Are steps 2 and 3 really necessary? If step 1 is incremented by 1 for each new viewer, each viewer will have a unique number which can be saved in a bitmap as an offset.

Comment: The mapping in steps 2 & 3 is needed if you need to translate offsets to/from your viewer IDs. Feel free to skip if not needed :)